# How does n increase its value from 0 to 1 or 2 in the Tower of Hanoi problem?

Tags: python

I am having trouble understanding how recursion works in the Tower of Hanoi problem. I am using the print function on line two to help me understand what is happening to n. My question is how does n become 1 or 2 in the output when there is only -1 in the function? I am having some serious difficulty in understanding recursion but I believe this is the easiest problem to work with to figure it out.

```
def hanoi(n,f,h,t):
    print("{}n={}, f={}, h={}, t={}"\
          .format(" "*(4-n),n,f,h,t))
    if n == 0:
        return
    else:
        hanoi(n-1,f,t,h)
        print(f"Move disk from {f} to {t}")
        hanoi(n-1,h,f,t)
    
hanoi(3, "A","B","C")
```

The output is this:

```
 n=3, f=A, h=B, t=C
  n=2, f=A, h=C, t=B
   n=1, f=A, h=B, t=C
    n=0, f=A, h=C, t=B
Move disk from A to C
    n=0, f=B, h=A, t=C
Move disk from A to B
   n=1, f=C, h=A, t=B
    n=0, f=C, h=B, t=A
Move disk from C to B
    n=0, f=A, h=C, t=B
Move disk from A to C
  n=2, f=B, h=A, t=C
   n=1, f=B, h=C, t=A
    n=0, f=B, h=A, t=C
Move disk from B to A
    n=0, f=C, h=B, t=A
Move disk from B to C
   n=1, f=A, h=B, t=C
    n=0, f=A, h=C, t=B
Move disk from A to C
    n=0, f=B, h=A, t=C
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It decreases in the recursion because of `hanoi(n-1, ...)`

Comment: Why do you think it's increasing?

Comment: I'm confused about how it gets from 0 to 1 or 2. I have no clue why it's increasing or what decreases in recursion means.

Comment: You don't understand that `n-1` is the value that's 1 less than the current value of `n`? So when it calls with that argument, it's decreased in the recursive call.

Comment: It doesn't increase. It just continues with the other `hanoi` call after. `print(f"Move disk from {f} to {t}")`

Comment: When the recursion returns, the local variable `n` still has its previous value. Variables are local to the specific invocation of the function.

Comment: That's fundamental to understanding any use of recursion. If you don't understand it, try looking at something similar, like factorial.

Comment: So why does it go to 1 or 2 and not 3 if it's previous, original value is 3?

Comment: Because it goes only a single step up the recursion chain. Only the initial call will ever have n==3, and all the following calls will have smaller number. When you return you go to the function that called it

Comment: So when it goes a step back up the recursion chain because of the return, why does it go to the print line rather than going to the 'hanoi(n-1,f,t,h)'; line and getting stuck in a loop?

Comment: It might be useful to think conceptually about what the algorithm is saying.  It says that the solution of moving N disks from the From stack to the To stack using the Hold stack is just to solve moving N-1 disks from the From stack to the Hold stack using the To stack, then moving the remaining Nth disk to the To stack, then solving the problem of moving N-1 disks from the Hold stack to To stack using the From stack.  The shifting of the order of f, h, and t in the recursive calls is important.

Comment: There is no looping.  The call with n=3 only makes two calls to hanoi with n=2.  Each call to hanoi with n=2 makes two calls to hanoi with n=1.  Each call to hanoi with n=1 makes two calls to hanoi with n=0, and the calls to hanoi with n=0 just return.

Comment: But do you know how it becomes 1 on line 8 rather than 2?